# Migrating Content from Blogger and Google Sites

Tags: migrations

I might be working on a project that would require me to transfer content from Blogger and Google Sites into Drupal. I was looking at [Google Sites Liberation](https://code.google.com/p/google-sites-liberation/) and using [Blogger Importer](https://www.drupal.org/project/blogger_importer) for the Blogger portion. My concern is getting the XHTML from Google Sites Liberation imported into Drupal and images transferred in from both Google Sites and Blogger. Does anyone have suggestions for a good way of migrating the content from Blogger and Google Sites? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/blogger_importer

Comment: Thanks! Also after more research, Feeds and Feeds Image Grabber might work as well.